Designing a Neural Network to predict a player's input in a 2D Fighting Game using game state information
I am currently trying to design a NN with the goal of broadly imitating the behavior of certain players in a specific 2D fighting game.
The game in question records "replays" of each game played, creating a large pool of data to work with. These replays contain not only the game state of each frame (such as positional values, action states etc.), but also what buttons were input by the player.
Input data for the NN would be the game state (or a series of game states), and output the predicted inputs for that game state.
I have set up a general MLP in PyTorch for this problem with the following architecture, treating it as a multilabel problem where each button input to make is a label to predict:
class BaseModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__()
        self.block_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256,128),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.block_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(128,64),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.block_3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(64,32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32,output_size)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.block_1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.block_2(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.block_3(x)
        return x
        

Data for this problem is derived from the replays.
Input data is first converted into a human-readable map (e.g. {"HP": 10000, "x":645.4273, "y":0.0000, "super_meter":32.6345, etc.} and then into numerical format in the form of a one-dimensional Tensor (e.g. [10000, 645.4273, 0.0000, 32.6345, etc.]).
Button inputs are similarly first converted into a human-readable map from the replays ({"A": 0, "B": 1, "up": 0, "down":0, "left":1, etc.}) and then converted into a one dimensional Tensor to be used as the truth labels for training, also just using the values of the map.
Currently, the loss function I use is Binary Cross Entropy, and the optimizer Adam. Output is passed through a sigmoid function, and if the value is over a certain threshold, the button is interpreted as pressed.
The current implementation works fairly poorly. Since most of the button inputs are 0 for each game state, the model achieves a low loss very quickly by predicting 0 for each button each frame.
What architectural changes should I experiment with to increase the performance of the model/deal with the problem that the model can very easily achieve a low loss?
Mind that the goal of this is to imitate player behavior, rather than "learn" how to play the game. If the player whose replay data was used to train the model does nothing but press a single button all the time, the model should reflect this behavior. Similarly, if the input player is a professional player whose actions are much more complex, the model should represent this behavior as well.

I think this post is unfortunately very vague. You need to define a clear goal before anybody can help you about "where to go." I'll also note that questions that are purely about programming are off topic here, so if your question is about how to better implement your code, then there are other places for that.

My problem mostly stems from not being able to tell what architectural changes I should experiment with to increase the performance of the model for this specific problem. If this is off-topic here, I understand. What would be a better place to discuss this?

For coding inquiries, Stack Overflow is an option. Statistics queries (and by extension NNs) are on topic so long as they encompass the meat of the question, but this question and your follow-up comment hint that this is more about programming than conceptually understanding NNs.

I don’t see this as an off-topic coding question. If we want to close this as a duplicate of the classic “hopeless” question, that could be argued, but how to get a neural network (or other model) to find needles in the haystack of zero-buttons seems totally within the purview of Cross Validated. $//$ @Michael What do you think of that linked question? Also, have you read some of our good posts on imbalance, such as the ones linked in my profile?

@Dave I can definitely see the parallels to the problem I'm having, but the lack of experience I have makes me hesitant to reach any further conclusions. As far as the posts go, I haven't read these yet, but will do so. I'm still a bit green when it comes to ML, so these resources are very helpful, thank you! Ultimately I believe this question might be in an awkward middle where it is both a question of concept (How to make the models "find the needles") and programming (How do I actually implement this concept). I understand if this might be a bit too bloated/vague, in that case.

@Michael You have to figure out what kind of model, neural network or otherwise, you want to implement before you can write the implementation code, yes?

@Dave That is true.

Wondering if you managed to find any solution to this problem?
I am also if wondering if previous game states are important for deciding a good output, maybe you can try that.

@Anton Ah... truth be told I'm a bit embarrassed about this thread. The architecture I am currently using is an LSTM that takes in a sequence of past game states, then predicts a future of button inputs. When I made this post I had overlooked a number of really obvious things (Not dealing with categorical data properly, not scaling my continuous data...), so let's just say the MLP architecture was the least of my problems.
This architecture seems to work OK, but the whole thing is still pretty WIP with a lot of problems/experimentation left.
